# search.templatetags.search_tags: No module named models

Tags: python, django

I'm reading "Beginning Django E-Commerce"
but I stopped with template tags

the error message :

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /
'search_tags' is not a valid tag library: ImportError raised loading search.templatetags.search_tags: No module named models
```

---

The app tree looks like:

```
search/
   -- __init__.py
   -- models.py
   templatetags/
      -- __init__.py
      -- search_tags.py
```

and search_tags.py

```
from django import template
from search.forms import SearchForm
import urllib

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag("tags/search_box.html")
def search_box(request):
    q = request.GET.get('q', '')
    form = SearchForm({'q': q })
    return {'form': form }

@register.inclusion_tag('tags/pagination_links.html')
def pagination_links(request, paginator):
    raw_params = request.GET.copy()
    page = raw_params.get('page', 1)
    p = paginator.page(page)
    try:
        del raw_params['page']
    except KeyError:
        pass
    params = urllib.urlencode(raw_params)
    return {'request': request,
            'paginator': paginator,
            'p': p,
            'params': params }
```

Do you have any ideas ? thank you

search.py

```
from models import SearchTerm
from catalog.models import Product
from django.db.models import Q

STRIP_WORDS = ['a','an','and','by','for','from','in','no','not','of','on','or','that','the','to','with']

#store the search text in db
def store(request, q):
    #if search term is three chars will store in db
    if len(q) > 2:
        term = SearchTerm()
        term.q = q
        term.ip_address = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
        term.user = None
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            term.user = requst.user
        term.save()

# get pruduct matching

def products(search_text):
    words = _prepate_words(search_text)
    products = Product_words(search_text)
    results = {}
    results['products'] = []
    # iterate through keywords
    for word in words:
        products = products.filter(Q(name__contains=word) | Q(description__icontains=word) | Q(sku__iexact=word) | Q(brand__icontains=word) | Q(meta_description__icontains=word) | Q(meta_keywords__icontains=word)) 
    results['products'] = products
    return results

#strip comon words , or limit to 5 words
def _prepate_words (search_text):
    words = search_text.splite()
    for common in STRIP_WORDS:
        if common in words:
            words.remove(common)
    return words[0:5]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, InvalidPage, EmptyPage
import search
from ecomstore import settings

def results(request, template_name="search/results.html"):
# get current search phrase
    q = request.GET.get('q', '')
# get current page number. Set to 1 is missing or invalid
    try:
        page = int(request.GET.get('page', 1))
    except ValueError:
        page = 1
# retrieve the matching products
        matching = search.products(q).get('products')
# generate the pagintor object
        paginator = Paginator(matching,
        settings.PRODUCTS_PER_PAGE)
    try:
        results = paginator.page(page).object_list
    except (InvalidPage, EmptyPage):
        results = paginator.page(1).object_list
# store the search
    search.store(request, q)
# the usual
    page_title = 'Search Results for: ' + q
    return render_to_response(template_name, locals(),
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: show you html. How are you calling the tag ?

Comment: {% load search_tags %}
and then
{% search_box request %}

Comment: One thing - you cannot get a request object - You have an error in the way you are registering the inclusion tag.

Comment: Do you want me to show other files ?

Comment: No.. The templatetag syntax is wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much mr karthikr :)
 how to solve the problem ?

Comment: yes :TemplateSyntaxError at /
'search_tags' is not a valid tag library: ImportError raised loading search.templatetags.search_tags: No module named models

Comment: where have you imported models in the app? Thats where the error is